# How does Yelp show up in iOS Spotlight search

Tags: ios, swift, search, ios-universal-links, corespotlight

Recently I was looking into a way to enable my app to be searchable inside iOS spotlight just like how Yelp does it.
Since data need to be fetched from my own service. I don't think using CoreSpotlight is a good option for me since it's mainly used for local data indexing and since I don't have a huge user base, relying on public indexing of NSUserActivity is probably not a good idea either.
My app supports universal linking so I am thinking whether it's possible to search for my page in Spotlight and open it in my app like Yelp.

[Yelp Search results in iOS Spotlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHxq.jpg)

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/116608/ios-9-app-search-tutorial-introduction-to-app-search. Has everything you need i think.

Comment: thanks Karthick, I will take a look at it

Comment: Please upvote my previous comment if you find it helpful so that it will be helpful for others